# Missing tabs in Media Library widget in Drupal 8.8

Tags: media

I'm trying to set up Media Library widget in Drupal 8.8. But for some reason, no tabs are available for selection in the widget settings. Please see following screenshots:

[image]
[image]

Do I need to install some additional module? I wasn't able to discover any settings, which would allow me to do this.

Comment: Hey Miloš, please let us know which steps exactly we need to follow to be able to reproduce this issue. Many thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I don't have much time. The reason is that I had only tab (browser) enabled in that field settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can happen when the field is not configured to reference any media types. It's a quirk of the underlying entity reference system that can be exposed under some circumstances.

The solution is to edit the field settings and ensure that the field is configured to reference at least two media types. (If only one media type can be referenced, the widget has no relevant settings to display.)